# Android: Swipe to Unlock screen or Default alarm stop screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-sdk-tools

In android default unlock screen, we swipe a lock to right to unlock. Same thing is there in default Alarm Service to stop alarm in Android (api 17). How it is possible to put this kind of functionality in my application?

[image]

Comment: Are you wanting this functionality on the lockscreen?

Comment: no. Actually I'm developing a AlarmClock application. So, to stop the alarm I want this screen. is it possible?

Comment: Hmm... You've lost me. You say no, but I know you mean yes...

Comment: Actually I want exactly default Alarm stop screen. So when screen locks and alarm rings I want to show this screen to stop alarm. Also when screen unlocked and alarm rings I want to show it.